# Listen incoming calls through BroadcastReceiver, without PhoneStateIntentReceiver or PhoneStateListener

Tags: android, android-broadcast

Is there any way to listen to incoming calls by extending BroadcastReceiver to listen to OS's broadcast,without using PhoneStateIntentReceiver or PhoneStateListener.
Also please tell me what will be action and permissions in manifest.

I've tried with as follows but it is not working for incoming calls but working for outgoing

The only one .java file of app is as follows(the app only one .java file and one manifest file)

```
package com.crsardar.media.audio;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class IncommingCallReceiverCRS extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("Chitta : ", "Its working");          
    }
}
```

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.crsardar.media.audio"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
  <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

    <receiver android:name="IncommingCallReceiverCRS" android:enabled="true"> 
        <intent-filter>
            <!--action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/-->
            <action  android:name="android.intent.action.ANSWER" >
            <category  android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

  </application>

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15564021/712526

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The action you have defined in your manifest is incorrect. this is an Action Intent that can be used to answer a call and not monitor incoming calls.

You can use two broadcast receivers that listen to [ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED) and [NEW_OUTGOING_CALL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL) broadcast intents.

The ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED will be received when there is a new incoming call, call answered or hangup (See the documentation for the EXTRAs received with this Intent).

The NEW_OUTGOING_CALL will be received when there is a new outgoing call placed on your device.

As for permissions, I think you got it about right in your manifest (I assume the RECORD_AUDIO permission is used for something else in your application)

Answer (score 0):

Here is My demo for android unit test. You can refer to it.

```
public interface ICallVerify {
    void onOutgoing(Context context, Intent intent);
    void onCallStateChange(Context context, Intent intent);
}

protected void setUpCallVerify(final ICallVerify callVerify) {  //listen ingoing and outgoing
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) { //state change
                Log.i(TAG, "outgoing call...");
                callVerify.onOutgoing(context, intent);
            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED)){ // state changed
                String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                if (state.equals("RINGING")) {
                    state += " number:" + intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "call state changed.... " + state);
                callVerify.onCallStateChange(context, intent);
            }
        }
    };

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL);
    ContextUtils.getTargetContext().registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

    try {
        latch.await(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Dont forget to add permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"></uses-permission>
```