# Incoming call broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have registered incomingCall broadcast receiver, and it works fine, but I need receiver when the call is established (or rejected). What I actually need is something to notify me when the user press 'Answer' or 'Reject' call.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can override your onReceive method of BroadcastReceiver as below

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

    if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
        //Phone is ringing
    } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
        //Call received
    } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
        //Call Dropped or rejected
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look also on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486793/ansroid-listen-incoming-calls-through-broadcastreceiver-without-phonestateint

Comment: ) is missed in line 4