# Activate my app or u can say a service when android gets a incoming call

Tags: android

I would like to build an android app that will read the incoming caller name or number(if its not stored in phonebook). but I dont know how to do it. I am very novice in android programming.
I guess i need to start a service like something that will run in background and listen of incoming calls and start my app.
could anybody please help with sample code? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is ultimately a similar question to yours; [Incoming call broadcast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224049/incoming-call-broadcast-receiver)  ... and yet again here; [Retrieve incoming call's phone number in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853220/retrieve-incoming-calls-phone-number-in-android?rq=1)

Please read about broadcast receivers here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html ...... also get familiar with telephony manager here; http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html

I think everything will make more sense then!